# Primitive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix $M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is said to be primitive if it exists an integer $k$ such as $M^k$ has all its coefficients strictly positive. My question is :

> If $M$ is primitive and if $N$ is similar to $M,$ say $N=PMP^{-1}$ with $P\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}),$ do we have that $N$ is primitive ?

I begin by seeing that $N^k=PM^kP^{-1},$ which reduces the problem. But I can't find the next step, every hint will be welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you multiply the primitive matrix $M=\pmatrix{1&1\cr1&1}$ on the left by the invertible matrix $P=\pmatrix{-1&1\cr 2&1}$, you find that the top row of $PM$ is $(0,0)$. The same is true, therefore, for $N:=PMP^{-1},$ and hence also for all powers of $N$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your counter example.